# FlagsAttribute for Enums

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

I am trying to study enum in C#. As I read in some documents I write a program. But I don't 
understand how this program is working. Can anybody help me about its working please?

I am posting my code below:

**Program 1 :**

```
public partial class MainPage {
    [Flags]
    enum Days {
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday ,
        Saturday,
        Sunday
    };

    // Constructor
  public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Days holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday;
        if ((Days.Sunday | holidays) == Days.Sunday) // This returns true. Why ?
            MessageBox.Show("True");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("False");
  }
```

**Program 2 :**

Here I assign integer values in enum

```
public partial class MainPage {
    [Flags]
    enum Days {
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 5,
        Thursday = 8,
        Friday = 10,
        Saturday = 3,
        Sunday = 0
    };

    // Constructor
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Days holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday;
        if ((Days.Sunday | holidays) == Days.Sunday) // Why this returns false ?
            MessageBox.Show("True");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("False");
  }
```

What is the difference in the if condition after assigning integer values in program 2?

Comment: Why down vote ?.. Is this a bad question ?

Comment: I don't believe it is a bad question, in fact I've ran into quite a few people who are starting out that have a problem understanding Flag enums. Perhaps a better title description would be more appropriate though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Jeremy's answer, considering his second (and correct) definition of Days
The binary representation is:

```
0000 0001   Monday
0000 0010   Tuesday
0000 0100   Wednesday
0000 1000   Thursday
0001 0000   Saturday
0010 0000   Sunday
```

Next your perform the following

```
var holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday;
```

This performs a bitwise or:

```
      0001 0000   Saturday
OR    0010 0000   Sunday
      --------------------
      0011 0000   Saturday | Sunday
```

Next you check the following

```
((Days.Sunday | holidays) == Days.Sunday)
```

Which means:

```
   0010 0000   Sunday
OR 0011 0000   holidays  (= Saturday | Sunday)
   ---------
   0011 0000   This is still holidays and does not equal Sundays
```

If you want to check if 'holidays' has the Sunday bit set you should use a bitwise AND

((Days.Sunday & holidays) == Days.Sunday)

```
    0010 0000   Sunday
AND 0011 0000   holidays  (= Saturday | Sunday)
    ---------
    0010 0000   Sunday
```

Also note that more recent version of the .NET Framework have
built-in support for flag checking:

```
var holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday
holidays.HasFlag(Days.Sunday)  //Will return true
holidays.HasFlag(Days.Monday)  //Will return false
```

Your definitions of the Days enum should not be used with [Flags],
if you apply the same logic from this post to the values in your definitions
you'll end up with some very weird results.

Comment: Thank you timothy. you explained it well. Now I got a clear idea.

Comment: @TimothyP you missed the `Days.Monday = 0` error too.  Quick, update :P

Answer (score 3):

enums by default start at 0, eg:

```
[Flags]
enum Days
{
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday = 5,
    Sunday = 6
};
```

I think you are getting confused with the bitwise operators on the enums. Usually to make enums work with bitwise operators you declare them like this:

```
[Flags]
enum Days
{
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 8,
    Saturday = 16,
    Sunday = 32
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are confusing the bit-wise operator `|` with the logical operator `||`.

In your original program, the Saturday is assigned 5 and Sunday is assigned 6.

Bitwise OR:

```
8 4 2 1 
0 1 0 1 = 5 Saturday
0 1 1 0 = 6 Sunday
-----------
0 1 1 1 = 7 Result (Holiday).
```

Bitwise OR:

```
8 4 2 1 
0 1 1 1 = 7 Holidays
0 1 1 0 = 6 Sunday
-----------
0 1 1 1 = 7 Result.
```

However I ran similar same code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    [Flags]
    enum Days
    {
        Monday,     //Default 0
        Tuesday,    //Default 1
        Wednesday,  //Default 3
        Thursday,   //Default 4
        Friday,     //Default 5
        Saturday,   //Default 6
        Sunday      //Default 7
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Days holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday;
        if ((Days.Sunday | holidays) == Days.Sunday) // This returns true. Why ?
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("False");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Result: `False` (not true as in your example).

As expected 7 is not equal to 6.  **My assumption is that there is missing code, or mis-typed code in your example.**

I'd highly recommend reading up on how the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is suppose to work if you use it properly, which involves creating the enum at bit values (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32).

If your code was corrected, then this would probably be more inline with what I believe you are looking for.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    [Flags]
    enum Days
    {
        Monday    = 1,
        Tuesday   = 2,   
        Wednesday = 4, 
        Thursday  = 8, 
        Friday    = 16,   
        Saturday  = 32, 
        Sunday    = 64
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Days holidays = Days.Sunday | Days.Saturday;

        if ((Days.Sunday | holidays) == holidays)
            Console.WriteLine("Sunday is a Holiday");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Sunday is a Holiday");

        if ((Days.Tuesday | holidays) == holidays)
            Console.WriteLine("Tuesday is not a Holiday");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Tuesday is not a Holiday");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Result: `Sunday is a Holiday` `Tuesday is not a Holiday`

This works because,

Bitwise OR:

```
64 32 16  8  4  2  1 
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0 = 32 Saturday
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 64 Sunday
----------------------
 1  1  0  0  0  0  0 = 96 Result (Holiday).
```

Bitwise OR:

```
64 32 16  8  4  2  1 
 1  1  0  0  0  0  0 = 96 Holiday
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 64 Sunday
----------------------
 1  1  0  0  0  0  0 = 96 Result (Holiday).
```

Bitwise OR:

```
64 32 16  8  4  2  1 
 1  1  0  0  0  0  0 = 96 Holiday
 0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 32 Tuesday
----------------------
 1  1  0  0  0  1  0 = 97 Result (Not Holiday).
```

Comment: `Days.Monday` should be defined as 1, otherwise `(Days.Monday | holidays) == holidays` is always true.  Also, the better test is `(Days.Sunday & holidays) == Days.Sunday` as this more clearly indicates the intent.